# How to go back with button in blade Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I want to create a back button in any Blade file. What is the PHP syntax that will allow me to return to the previous page without redirecting?

In principle I do not know in advance the link of the previous page to do `Redirect::route("/{previous-page}");`.

I tried this `Redirect::back()` which doesn't work, and I have to know the previous page to do `Redirect::route("/{previous-page}");`

Whereas `href="/"` has the consequence of entering the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without redirect. Try this `{{url()->previous()}}` in your blade file where you want to put the back button.
Here is an example with the boostrap button.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{url()->previous()}}"> Go Back </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `{{url()->previous()}}` will fails when we reloaded the page by placing the cursor in the url and press enter, `window.history.back()` will help you redirect to previous url

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.history.back()">Back</a>
```